# How to force font-weight on all children, but respect the nested depth

Tags: html, css

I'm displaying some HTML markup which was originally created in Flash. Flash has an attribute called "FACE" which applies a custom font to the tag. I'm processing the markup on the server side before it's sent to the browser, it converts FONT tags into spans and the FACE attribute into a class name, e.g. "Arial" or "ArialBold".

I want to style the text to match the custom fonts (so Arial can only show font-weight:normal, and ArialBold can only show font-weight: bold). The problem is my css isn't handling it how Flash would.

Flash might have this markup:

```
<font face="ArialBold">
  <font face="Arial"><span><b>Some text<b><span></font>
</font>
```

And it will display like this:

> Some text

Here the Arial font is overriding the ArialBold font because it's nested deeper and the  tag renders as normal text because the Arial font doesn't have bold characters included.

In the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kHFX8/2/) however, html/css will show the text as:

> **Some text**

So, my question is, how do I fix the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kHFX8/2/), so that the outputted text to display is:

> **Normal bold here**
>
> Hello World Good bye
>
> **Hello World Good bye**

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kHFX8/2/)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just with this simple css:

```
.Arial *, .ArialBold * { font-weight: inherit; }
.Arial { font-weight: normal; }
.ArialBold { font-weight: bold; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kHFX8/15/

Comment: The problem there is the second line shows a bold "Hello World". Everything under Arial needs to be normal text.

Comment: Even if its again in a `b`-element?

Comment: so target the b tag and make it font weight normal. http://jsfiddle.net/kHFX8/12/

Comment: Ah that's great, didn't think to use inerhit. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kHFX8/11/

```
.Arial > .ArialBold b{
   font-weight: bold;
}

.Arial {
   font-weight: normal;
}
.ArialBold, .Arial > .ArialBold span{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't guarantee Arial or ArialBold will be direct children of each other. There is all sorts of markup in between (p tags, list items etc).

Comment: I'm afraid, unless you can discern some sort of pattern then you're in for a very hard time ! Best you can do is try and assign a proprietary classname to the surrounding <span>